# How to run bash scripts with docker containers in correct order?

Tags: bash, shell-script, process, docker

I have a main bash script that executes several smaller bash scripts (and each smaller script runs a docker container)
But I want the 2nd script to run only after the first has finished executing, and so on.
That is, I want the processes of each script to NOT run simultaneously.
Example:

```
1st_script.sh param1 param2 param3
2nd_script.sh param1 param2
```

Suggestions online are not working for me.
I tried to get PID of 1st_script with:

```
1st_Script & echo $!
```

to then use `ps -p <PID> || <2nd_script>`
But although `<1st_Script> & echo $!` gives a PID, when I check if process is there with `ps -p <PID>` there's nothing. I know 1st_script is running cause the docker container it runs is listed with `docker ps`. So it's process should also be listed with `ps -p <PID>`

`1st_Script && 2nd_Script && 3rd_Script && ...` is not a option cause I have a lot of scripts and is not readable

Comment: Reading between the lines it seems that you are actually trying to ask how to run *Docker* commands and wait for them. It would be much clearer if you showed which commands exactly; in its current form, your question doesn't really make sense at all.

Answer (score 1):

Continuation lines can greatly improve readability:

```
script1 && script2 && script3 && scriptn
```

versus

```
script1 \
  && script2 \
  && script3 \
  && scriptn
```

But I'm having trouble reproducing your problem. What gives you the impression that your scripts are *not* running sequentially?

I made two test scripts that each contained

```
echo hello
sleep 15s
```

and then a script that contained only

```
./script1
./script2
```

and measured the wait using `time` to get the following output

```
hello
hello

real    0m30.003s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.001s
```

If the scripts ran concurrently, the total time taken would have been less than 30 seconds.

Is your issue instead that you want the *container* to stop running before moving to the next script?

Comment: Yes, want the container to stop/finish running before moving to the next script. At the end, it worked by doing: dockerId=$(docker command) and then docker wait $dockerId. This inside each  small script. Also worked by just removing the '-d' flag from docker run command

Comment: If you can, make sure to answer your own question with sample code and mark it answered so others can find your solution too!